# Overlay text Label to UIImageView defined in Xib

Tags: ios, uiimageview, label

I have a `UIImageView` (`uiv1`) and `Label` (`lab1`) defined in a xib file. Progmatically, I have a fixed array with different lengths of text I want to display as overlaid on `uiv1`. Thing is, for now, I can make `lab1` long enough to accomodate my longest string, however sometime down the road I may need to determine string length on the fly and update `lab1` accordingly. How do I update the dimensions of `lab1` to get it to display longer text? Is there another way of overlaying text on a `UIImageView`? I've also turned off autolayout to remedy another problem with `uiv1` related to resetting it's position when the background image was updated (possibly related?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good way to overlay text on an imageView... You can get the expected text length using the following and then update `lab1.frame` to match the right size.

```
NSString *someString = @"Hello World";
UIFont *yourFont = // [UIFont ...]
CGSize stringBoundingBox = [someString sizeWithFont:yourFont];
```

The size will give you `stringBoundingBox.height` and `stringBoundingBox.width`